# how can i detect when flickr photos become unavailable?

Tags: ruby, image, flickr, broken-links

How can I tell programatically when an embedded/blogged flickr image is replaced with a "photo no longer available" image?

With Ruby if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Flickr `flickr.photos.getPerms` API method with the photo ID extracted from any URLs you have.

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getPerms.html

This would tell you if the photo is missing or has had it's permissions changed to prevent public viewing.

Various Ruby wrappers are available for the Flickr API.